# Reading data from the web using arduino wifi shield

Tags: c, arduino, wifi

I have arduino wifi shield.I want to read text file from web page that has some commands.I will parse the commands from html file and going to control arduino from the web page like that..
Problem is i don't understand how should i read the data so arduino will remotely open the led.If i use the code below every time i need to open serial monitor to switch on led.But i want this process to completed inside of arduino,i don't want to depend on serial monitor.As i said it should work when not plugged to computer.How can i do that i want to know what should i understand first to do this.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
char lf=10;
int x=0;
char ssid[] = "AIRTIES_RT-205"; //  your network SSID (name)
char pass[] = "";    // your network password (use for WPA, or use as key for WEP)
int keyIndex = 0;            // your network key Index number (needed only for WEP)
String readString, readString1;
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
// if you don't want to use DNS (and reduce your sketch size)
// use the numeric IP instead of the name for the server:
//IPAddress server(74,125,232,128);  // numeric IP for Google (no DNS)
char server[] = "taylankaan-001-site1.myasp.net";    // name address for Google (using DNS)

// Initialize the Ethernet client library
// with the IP address and port of the server
// that you want to connect to (port 80 is default for HTTP):
WiFiClient client;

void setup() {
  //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }

  // check for the presence of the shield:
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
    Serial.println("WiFi shield not present");
    // don't continue:
    while (true);
  }

  String fv = WiFi.firmwareVersion();
  if ( fv != "1.1.0" )
    Serial.println("Please upgrade the firmware");

  // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
  //  Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network. Change this line if using open or WEP network:
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid);

    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);
  }

  //printWifiStatus();

  //Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server...");
  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("connected to server");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.println("GET /asp.txt HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: taylankaan-001-site1.myasp.net");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  }
}
String command;

void loop() {

while(client.connected() && !client.available()) delay(1); //waits for data
  while (client.connected() || client.available()) { //connected or data available
    char c = client.read();

    if (c == '\n') {
      parseCommand(command);
      command = "";
    }
    else {
      command += c;
    }

  }

   if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting from server.");
    client.stop();

    while (true);
  }
  }





void printWifiStatus() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
    Serial.println("Connected to network");

    Serial.print(WiFi.SSID());


 if(WiFi.RSSI()>=-35){
     Serial.println("Very good connection");
   }
   if(WiFi.RSSI()>=-65 && WiFi.RSSI()<-35){
     Serial.println("%50 good connected");
   }
   if(WiFi.RSSI()<-65){
     Serial.println("Worst connection");
   }


  }




void parseCommand(String com) {
  String part1;
  String part2;

  //PINON 13

  part1 = com.substring(0, com.indexOf(" "));

  part2 = com.substring(com.indexOf(" ") + 1);

  if (part1.equalsIgnoreCase("openled")) {

    digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well this was funny but after realizing its about serial port i tried few things and the reason for me to wait serial port is :
while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }
i didnt care what for this used and now see it was preventing everything unless serial port is open.